# Value maps (comboboxes) doesn't follow when exporting to .qlr (layer definition)

Tags: qgis, combo-box

I added value maps (comboboxes) to some fields in QGIS 2.18.15 but when exporting to .qlr (layer definition) the comboboxes doesn't follow. 
Any idea why?